# Selecting ranges in Spreadsheetlight

Tags: c#, excel

Does anyone know if its possible to select a range, or maybe a list of `SLcell` in Spreadsheetlight? My goal is to do a foreach loop. Currently I am using nested for loops.

```
foreach(SLCell cell in myRange)
{
}
```

Interop would be:

```
Excel.Range myRange= sheet.get_Range("A1", "B4");

Excel.Range myRange= sheet.get_Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(4,2));
```

Comment: how can we select a single SLCell ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use GetCells() from your SLDocument instance.
Then foreach(var cell in cells)